# Install / Update mysql-connector for Python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pip, mysql-connector

I have had no success at installing the MySQL Python connector on ubuntu 14.04. it appears that the production environment has version 1.1.6 installed. I have tried removing it with both pip and apt-get. I have attempted to update it also and have had no luck.

The command below does not work, I have tried with both "mysql-connector" and "mysql-connector-python"

`pip install --user --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python`
`

> Downloading/unpacking mysql-connector-python
>    Could not find any
>   downloads that satisfy the requirement mysql-connector-python Cleaning
>   up...
>  No distributions at all found for mysql-connector-python
>   Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log`

If I run the command above, with just mysql-connector, it fails with an error about external managment. 
`"error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized"`

I have also tried to manually remove it from "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql_connector_python-1.1.6.egg-info" and that seems to have made no difference.

I have also downloaded the .deb from MySQL:
"mysql-connector-python-cext_2.1.3-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb" and used dpkg to install it, but that fails, as well as update fails.

Any advice?